# How to do paging in "foreach" statement in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets say i have this

```
<table>
while (reader.Read())
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@reader["title"]</td>
            <td>
                <a href="~/download.cshtml?id=@reader["id"]">Download</a>

            </td>

        </tr>

        }
</table>
```

which will generate table with title of a file and its download link..

my question how can i do paging for this table, each page contains 10 files for example ?

its ASP.net website with razor syntax, if there's an easy way in ordinary asp.net id like to see it.

Comment: check : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa

Comment: my website isnt on MVC

Comment: the syntax you have shown is of razor view engine

Comment: yes razor syntex webpages isnt the same as MVC website.